# HTML5 / JavaScript Pong game

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, game, html5

I am nearly done developing my pong game (made in HTML5 / JavaScript), and I would like some constructive criticism on my code.

[Full code](http://code.google.com/p/pong-redux/source/browse/#git%2Fjs)

**Initialization:**

```
var play2 = false;

function init() {
//setup canvas
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
ctxW = ctx.canvas.width;
ctxH = ctx.canvas.height;
ctxWD2 = ctxW / 2;
ctxHD2 = ctxH / 2;
//var arrays
KEY = {
        UP: 38,
        DOWN: 40,
        W: 87,
        S: 83,
        D: 68,
        P: 80,
        O: 79,
        I: 73,
        SPACE: 32
}
pong = {
        ver: "v1.6beta",
        fps: 60,
        win: 10,
        pressedKeys: [],
        ntfs: [],
        pwrs: [],
        debug: true,
        paused: false,
        respawning: false,
        ball: {         
                x: null,
                y: null,
                w: 20,
                wM: 0,
                h: 20,
                hM: 0,
                s: null,
                sM: 0,
                dirX: 1,
                dirY: 1,
                c: "#FFFFFF",
        },
        pA: {
                x: 100,
                y: null,
                w: 10,
                h: 80,
                hM: 0,
                s: 8,
                sM: 0,
                c: "#FFFFFF",
        },
        pB: {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                w: 10,
                h: 80,
                hM: 0,
                s: 8,
                sM: 0,
                c: "#FFFFFF",
        },
        sA: {
                val: 0,
                x: null,
                y: 20,
                c: "#FFFFFF",
        },
        sB: {
                val: 0,
                x: null,
                y: 20,
                c: "#FFFFFF",
        },
        cmpt: {
                val: false,
                txt: null,
                txt2: "Press SPACE to Play Again",
                x: null,
                y: 20,
                c: "#FFFFFF",
        },
        pwr: {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                w: 10,
                h: 10,
                s: 5,
                c: "#FFFFFF",
                move: false,
                dir: null,
                obj: null,
                rsp: 0,
        },
        pAI: {
                pA: true,
                pB: true,
        },
        pAIOpt: {
                miss: 0,
                diff: 1200,
        },
        render: {
                ball: true,
                pA: true,
                pB: true,
                sA: true,
                sB: true,
                ntf: true,
                pwr: false,
                cmpt: false,
                paused: false,
                version: true
        }
};
//redefine sub-arrays
ball = pong.ball;
pA = pong.pA;
pB = pong.pB;
sA = pong.sA;
sB = pong.sB;
cmpt = pong.cmpt;
pwr = pong.pwr;
pAI = pong.pAI;
pAIOpt = pong.pAIOpt;
render = pong.render;
//adjust positioning according to window size
ball.s = ctxW / 250;
pA.y = (ctxH - pA.h) / 2;
pB.y = (ctxH - pB.h) / 2;
pB.x = ctxW - 100 - pB.w;
sA.x = ctxWD2 - 200;
sB.x = ctxWD2 + 200;
cmpt.x = ctxWD2;
//initialize key listeners
for (var keyCode in KEY) {
        if (KEY.hasOwnProperty(keyCode)) {
                pong.pressedKeys[KEY[keyCode]] = {
                        isDown: false,
                        wasDown: false
                };
        }
}
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
        for (var x in KEY) {
                if (KEY[x] == e.which) {
                        pong.pressedKeys[e.which].isDown = true;
                }
        }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
        for (var x in KEY) {
                if (KEY[x] == e.which) {
                        pong.pressedKeys[e.which].isDown = false;
                }
        }
});

//initialize startloop
if (!play2) {
        pong.startloop = setInterval(startloop,1000/pong.fps);
}
else if (play2) {
        respawnBall();
        pong.gameloop = setInterval(gameloop,1000/pong.fps);
}
}

function startloop() {
checkResize();
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctxW,ctxH)
ctx.font = "60px pong";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.fillText("Press SPACE to Start",ctxW / 2,ctxH / 2);
if (pong.pressedKeys[KEY.SPACE].isDown && !pong.pressedKeys[KEY.SPACE].wasDown) {
        //initialize gameloop
        clearInterval(pong.startloop);
        //get the ball rolling (not really)
        respawnBall();
        pong.gameloop = setInterval(gameloop,1000/pong.fps);
}
for (var keyCode in KEY) {
        if (KEY.hasOwnProperty(keyCode)) {
                pong.pressedKeys[KEY[keyCode]].wasDown = pong.pressedKeys[KEY[keyCode]].isDown;
        }
}
}
```

**Render function:**

```
function renderGraphics() {
//resize if window size changes
checkResize();
//clear canvas
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctxW,ctxH)
//draw ball
if (render.ball) {
        ctx.fillStyle = ball.c;
        ctx.fillRect(ball.x,ball.y,ball.w + ball.wM,ball.h + ball.hM);
}
//draw pA
if (render.pA) {
        ctx.fillStyle = pA.c;
        ctx.fillRect(pA.x,pA.y,pA.w,pA.h + pA.hM);
}
//draw pB
if (render.pB) {
        ctx.fillStyle = pB.c;
        ctx.fillRect(pB.x,pB.y,pB.w,pB.h + pB.hM);
}
//draw pwr
if (render.pwr) {
        ctx.fillStyle = pwr.c;
        ctx.fillRect(pwr.x,pwr.y,pwr.w,pwr.h);
}
//draw scores
ctx.font = "120px pong";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
if (render.sA) {
        ctx.fillStyle = sA.c;
        ctx.fillText(sA.val,sA.x,sA.y);
}
if (render.sB) {
        ctx.fillStyle = sB.c;
        ctx.fillText(sB.val,sB.x,sB.y);
}
//draw win screen
if (render.cmpt) {
        ctx.fillStyle = cmpt.c;
        ctx.fillText(cmpt.txt,cmpt.x,cmpt.y);
        ctx.font = "60px pong";
        ctx.fillText(cmpt.txt2,cmpt.x,ctxH - 100);
}
//draw pause screen
if (render.paused) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fillText("Paused",ctxWD2,20);
}
//draw version number
if (render.version) {
        ctx.font = "20px pong";
        ctx.textAlign = "right";
        ctx.fillText(pong.ver,ctxW - 5,5);
}
//draw ntf
if (render.ntf) {
        pong.ntfs.forEach(function ntf(I) {
                ctx.font = I.f;
                ctx.textAlign = I.a;
                ctx.textBaseline = I.b;
                ctx.fillStyle = I.c;
                if (I.render) {
                        ctx.fillText(I.txt,I.x,I.y);
                }
        });
}
}
```

**AI calculations:**

```
function calculateAI() {
for (paddle in pAI) {
        var obj = pong[paddle];
        var by = ctxHD2;
        if (!pAI[paddle]) {
                return;
        }
        if (pAIOpt.miss == 0) {
                switch(rand(pAIOpt.diff)) {
                        case 0:
                                pAIOpt.miss = 30;
                                break;
                        case 1:
                                pAIOpt.miss = 60;
                                break;
                }
        }
        else if (pAIOpt.miss > 0) {
                pAIOpt.miss--;
                return;
        }
        switch(obj) {
                case pA:
                        var dir = -1;
                        break;
                case pB:
                        var dir = 1;
                        break;
        }
        if (dist(ball,obj) <= ctxW * 0.3 && ball.dirX == dir) {
                by = ball.y + (ball.h / 2) - ((obj.h + obj.hM) / 2);
        }
        if (dist(pwr,obj) <= ctxW * 0.3 && render.pwr) {
                if (ball.dirX == dir * -1 || dist(ball,obj) > ctxW * 0.2) {
                        by = pwr.y + (pwr.h / 2) - ((obj.h + obj.hM) / 2);
                }
        }
    if (by > obj.y + ((obj.h + obj.hM) / 2)) {
        obj.y += obj.s + obj.sM;
    }
    else if (by < obj.y - ((obj.h + obj.hM) / 2)) {
            obj.y -= obj.s + obj.sM;
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a "pro member" but can still leave a few comments. They are not too important anyway. You should move to more complicated games and will see for yourself whether you agree with me or not.

- Please indent your code properly.
- Do you know about JavaScript closures? I'm sure they could be helpful here.
- Your variable names could be more explicit. What is `cmpt`, `sM` or `val`?. If you're really worried about .js size, minify it.
- I realize that most game frameworks say that the origin is at some corner (eg. (0,0) is bottom left), but you could avoid to repeat yours? Never use names like elf if the origin was in the middle. For example, to check if a player won a point or not, you could write:

  ```
  if (Math.abs(ball.x) > ctxWD2) {
      winner = ball.x < 0 ? sA : sB;
      winner.val++;
  }
  ```
- It feels weird to separate the `respawnBall()` call from the "Player 1 wins" code.
- This is probably a bug: you probably meant `break;`, you don't want to exit the loop too quickly if there's an AI next.
      if (!pAI[paddle]) {
              return;
      }
- You're mixing rendering logic and main logic, which is OK for pong but will bite you whenever you're making something bigger. I would prefer having a few states ("playing", "display score", ...) and having the rendering function deciding what to render than all those `render.xxx = true` in the code
- The powerup animation is very nice. :)
- Please use the ternary operator when you're making assignments:

  ```
  switch(obj) {                                                                                                            
      case pA:                                                                                                             
          var dir = -1;                                                                                                    
          break;                                                                                                           
      case pB:                                                                                                             
          var dir = 1;                                                                                                     
         break;                                                                                                           
  }
  ```

  could become `dir = obj == pA ? -1 : 1`. You can also use a `if()`, but the switch feels overkill.

Comment: Wow, great response! 1. How is it not indented properly as is? 2. No I don't, do you have a link to more info? 3. I shrunk them to make coding faster, I'll include a reference to say which is which. 4. I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not using a framework. 5. I separated it because I call it from various places. 6. I used `return` over `break` purposely. I didn't want the function to continue. 7. I know my render segment is a bit haphazard, I'll take a look at cleaning it up. 8. Thanks :) 9. I didn't even know JS had a ternary operator. I'll put that in there.

Comment: Overall, thanks for all the feedback! You definitely made some good points. I will try implementing them and see how it goes. If I don't get any better answers within the next couple days, I'll award you the bounty :)

Comment: RE: Indention: You haven't indented the the function bodys and 8 spaces is far too much indention. Two to four are used normally. Plus you should use some empty lines now and then.

Comment: Also, shorter variable names don't make the code faster.

Comment: RoToRa, he's saying they make the *coding* faster. Which could make sense, except that I'm sure he's not spending most of his time typing, but thinking. For indentation, 8 spaces is OK, but there are still problems, eg. the last two lines of calculateAI.

Comment: 1. For example the first two lines of the AI calculations 2. You actually used that for powerups. You can do that in other cases too. 4. I noticed that you're not using a framework, which is why I'm suggesting changing the frame of reference in a way that could work better for Pong. Nevermind. 5. It's not really about respawnBall(), but about doing the pong.win check in different places. Not important. 6. Why having two keys in pAI then?

Comment: @Cygal My code is actually indented 4 lines, but this website interpreted  it as 8. I don't quite understand what the issue is with the first two lines of the AI calculations. The way I made that is so it will only calculate the AI for the paddles in pAI where they equal true, without duplicating all the calculations. This lets me toggle the AI for each paddle mid-game.

Comment: @ryansworld10 Re: 4 vs. 8 spaces. You are mostlikely using tabs for indention, which each editor/environment interprets differently (8 is a standard width). You should be using spaces for indention instead to avoid that.

Comment: @RoToRa Yes I am using tabs. It makes it much faster for me to write code. I guess I could convert tabs to spaces before sharing the code.

Comment: This is personal preference, keep tabs if you want. However, I am a bit puzzled that you don't indent the body of your functions, the same way you do it for your if blocks. That's all.

Comment: @Cygal I don't indent my function bodies because that would cause pretty much _all_ my code to be indented. It just seems annoying to me. Idk, I guess its just one of my quirks :P

Comment: @Cygal If no one else answers by tomorrow, I'll award you the bounty for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some random thoughts:

- The whole code seems a quite unstructured. For example, it's complete unclear why which function is in which file. And the unreadable short variable names don't help there either.
- There is a lot of code duplication.
- There are virtually no comments that really explain things, especially the many calculations.

Comment: 1. I group the functions into the different files based on what they are related to. For instance, all the powerup functions are in the `powerup.js` file, and all the functions I call from various places that don't specifically fall into another category, I put in the `util.js` file. All the functions called in the gameloop in `gameloop.js`, and the code that runs once when the game starts in `init.js`. 2. I know there is a lot in `powerup.js`, but how would I fix it? 3. I'll add them in once I fix some of the other issues.

Comment: Re: 1. I didn't say there wasn't a logic, but that the logic isn't really noticable. Especially the "utils.js" seems like a collection of random mixture of actual utility functions such as `rand` and game logic functions. Re: 2. I'll post some suggestions (possibly tomorrow).

Answer (score 2):

Your application should be defined in a scope.

like

`PingPong = {}; PingPong.calculateAI= function(){...}`

Comment: I do this for most everything in the app, except the functions. I don't see how doing that for my functions would help in any way.

Comment: if you release this a plugin, it is safe to have your own scope otherwise it may conflict with some other functions.

Comment: I see. I will consider doing that if I ever release it as one.

Comment: @ryansworld It's not only the functions. You've declared almost all variables in the global scope, too. Using a single namespace/scope allows your code the run along side other JavaScript in the same document without the danger of names to clash.

Comment: @RoToRa When I re-defined all the sub-objects of `pong` to global objects, I did that so I didn't have to type `pong.` before every var. If you could suggest a better way to do that I would love to hear it. (Please don't interpret that as sarcasm :P)

Comment: @ryansworld10 While it's certainly valid wanting not to type more than needed, creating global variables isn't the solution. Also, in good programming, readability goes before less typing. If you want to type less you should use an Editor/IDE with code completion. You could have saved much more typing by avoiding code duplication instead of shorting the variables.